# how to convert a string into a conditional expression in java (Android)?

Tags: java, android, string, conditional-statements

I have a String "a>b" and I want to convert into a normal conditional expression.
How to do this in **Android** means using only JSE.

```
String abc = "a>10";
if(abc){
 // TO SOME TASK
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605032/using-eval-in-java

Comment: but javax.script.ScriptEngine and javax.script.ScriptEngineManager are not available in android.

Comment: You can take a look at Parboiled to parse simple boolean expressions.

Comment: I don't think there is any need to bring JSE into the picture. I would just use regex to get the index of the special conditional character. Then use String[] parts = abc.split(specialChar) and write conditional code like if(specialChar=='>'){doSomething with parts[0] and parts[1].}

Comment: Write a parser. Can't get around needing to write one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluate String as a condition Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917878/evaluate-string-as-a-condition-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using a "helper" method that returns a boolean result, so the statement would look something like this

```
String abc = "a>10";

if(stringToConditional("a>b"))
{
  //TO SOME TASK
}

private boolean stringToConditional(String str)
{
  //code here
}
```

From there, the "helper" method can split the string into three parts using regex. A helpful, abet dense, tutorial can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/intro.html). From there, a and b can be parsed using JSE methods. It looks something like this:

```
String a = "1.21";
double a1 = Double.parseDouble(a); //a1 is now equal to 1.21
```

From there, the next step would be to compare the conditional string (">", "<=", "==", etc.) to a list of known operators, and then testing the operation and returning the result as the method's boolean return. For example:

```
String operator = ">=";
if (operator.equals(">="))
{
  return a1>=b1;
}
...
```

Hopefully I wasn't too unclear or off the mark. I'd be happy to elaborate, clarify or simplify. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

In Java we can use [javaScriptEngine API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/):

```
String condExptn="34>5&&78<90";
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
result = engine.eval(condExptn.toString().trim());
```